# package identity associated with this update doesn't match what's in the uploaded package

Tags: windows-phone, package, publish, visual-studio-cordova

I am in the situation with the environment.

VS 2013, Update 4, CTP 3.1 Cordova.

I have been struggling for the past 1 week to publish the app to stores as it is stopping with error

"The package identity associated with this update doesn't match what's in the uploaded package".

Some gentleman has suggested to update to 2015 and ctp6 to pass through this problem.

Any alternatives that I can get here?

I tried all alternatives but could not get pass through this.

Thanks

Comment: If anybody faces the above problem, please follow the link. https://github.com/Chuxel/taco-tricks/tree/master/plugin-windows-package-fix

Answer (score 0):

If this is for the Windows platform (and I assume it is based on your tags), try installing this workaround plugin:

https://github.com/Chuxel/taco-tricks/tree/master/plugin-windows-package-fix

This should be resolved in VS 2015 but is an issue in VS 2013.